# FB share dialog cancel callback not working in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio

I'm trying to share some text from my android app to FB.
There's no login functionality, just sharing is used.

The text does get shared on FB, but the ShareDialog callback always returns to onSuccess, even if sharing was cancelled.

I'm using below code:

```
//FB
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                    .setContentDescription(
                            message)
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(contentUrl))
                    .build();

        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(mActivity);
        // this part is optional
        shareDialog.registerCallback(MainActivity.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.yourpostsharedsuccessfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

And using this in my Activity:

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Please help.
I need to know when post was successfully shared and when it was cancelled.
I'm using FB sdk 4.1.0.

Comment: You can get the exact callback(if the text is posted or not) only if you use  Facebook Api.

Comment: Please check how to do it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Why do you need to know the difference? The share dialog only tells you whether the user canceled if they have logged into FB via your app. See the FAQ here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#onsuccess

Comment: @pratiti-systematix have you found the answer? maybe i've an answer

Comment: Yes, because I need to have publish permissions, which aren't there while I use Share Intent from android. Thus no content is shared. Please share, if you've got a solution.